# c# winforms - how to populate DataGridViewRowHeaders and FirstRow - like a Calendar

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, calendar

c# winforms

On a form I have a DataGridView and three buttons.

Buttons are: lastMonth, currentMonth and nextMonth.

dgv has 30 or 31 columns (each column is a day of the month).

ColumnHeaders are: 1 2 3 ... (date).

I should populate firstRow of dgv with the dayNames (first letter) - M T V ...

something like:

1  2  3  4  5... till 30 or 31   // these are column headers

M  T W  T  F... till end        // these are firstRowCells

Click on Buttons should change the first row according to first letter of the day in corresponding month.
Anu idea about coding ? Thanks.

Comment: Which bit do you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

I'd look on CodeProject for ideas, such as [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38699/A-Professional-Calendar-Agenda-View-That-You-Will).

http://www.codeproject.com/search.aspx?q=calendar&doctypeid=1%3b2%3b3&ratingmin=4.5

Comment: ThankYou Grant, link is very helpful but...
I downloaded some project's sourcocodes, converted them in VS 2010 version, and got a bounch of errors (variables are not declared or never used...)
Do you now maybe, what should i do to have these examples working?